# How to get the id of DataSource bean automatically registered by Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, datasource

I use Spring Boot in my project, and I configured the related datasource information in the `application.yaml` file and Spring Boot will use these information to generate a bean of `DataSource` type. Now I need reference this bean in a Spring xml config file. But I do not know what's the ID or name of this bean. How can I get it?

- application.yaml

  ```
  spring:
    datasource:
      url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xmaster
      username: root
      password: root
      driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  ```
- xml config file

  ```
  ...
  <int-jdbc:outbound-gateway id="findAllOutboundGateway"
                             request-channel="bio-security/datasource/findAllChannel"
                             data-source="?"  //NEEDED HERE
                             query="SELECT * FROM BOOKS"
                             reply-channel="datasourceOut"
                             max-rows-per-poll="0"/>
  ...
  ```

  Thanks!

Comment: Could you post your XML or the Java's config?

Comment: @BrunoDM I added the xml and yaml configuration code.

Comment: Have you tried to put `datasource=datasource`?

Comment: @BrunoDM Not yet. I will try soon. But I print all of the bean names using `ApplicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()` and I find a bean named `datasource`:)

Comment: I believe you have create the datasource wrong. Take a look at this tutorial..http://smasue.github.io/spring-yml-datasources It creates a child at `datasource`, looks like a name/id of the datasource. Try it too